# Why does AJAX have cache issue?

Tags: ajax, caching

I am wondering why AJAX has cache issue, what's the difference between AJAX post/get invocation and ordinary form post/get invocation? As I know, I don't have to consider cache issue when I use form post/get method, but as for AJAX, I should add a timestamp parameter at the end of query string. Anyone can explain to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it wrong - you *do* have to consider caches when performing an ordinary GET. It's just that, broadly speaking, it's not a big problem if a cached page is served when you are just browsing the net.

When you are using AJAX, you are commonly updating a record and then wanting to view the result, so caching becomes undesirable.